# Micro USB Flash Drive on Android Without OTG Cable

Tags: usb

I have bought a [Samsung 128GB USB 3.0 Flash Drive Duo](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B017DH3NXI) in hopes of being able to use the Micro-USB side with my [Sony XPeria Z3+](https://www.sonymobile.com/us/products/phones/xperia-z3-plus/). When plugging it in, I got no response or message from the phone. I tried looking up the reason why on google, but all i get are these responses on how to use a usb drive with the phone by using an OTG cable.

Is there any way that I can get the micro-usb side working on my phone? It must have been put on the drive for a reason, right?

Comment: Did you verify that your Z3+ phone works in host mode? Did you try "OTG" cable/adapter with regular Type-A flash drive?

Comment: A quick Google search took me to [this page](http://support.sonymobile.com/gb/xperiaz3compact/userguide/Connecting-your-device-to-USB-peripherals/), which suggests you have to go to `Settings > Device connection > USB Connectivity > Detect USB device`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case there is no need for an usb OTG cable. It does nothing else then wiring the USB Type A connector to the micro usb connector, there is no electronic involved. The same goes for the micro usb connector on the stick itself. It's directly wired to the type A connector.

Usually the device should recognise and mount the stick automatically although this can be different depending on the manufacturer. I assume that sony's android implementation does not mount it automatically, but they have a [manual](http://support.sonymobile.com/gb/xperiaz3compact/userguide/Connecting-your-device-to-USB-peripherals/) (thanks ernie for the link).

From Sony:

```
Find and tap Settings > Device connection > USB Connectivity > Detect USB device.
```

Answer (score 0):

Android devices should automatically mount drives like that one so the only thing I can think of that may be causing you issues is that the drive may be too big. Some companies don't support drives of certain sizes so that people buy phones with more storage. Usually this is limited to sd cards but I've seen some devices from other manufacturers that don't allow drives of certain sizes via OTG. If you're able to get it working with a 64gb or 32gb drive then I think size constraints may be your issue.

Also it could just be that you got a bad drive. If you have a friend or other device I would try plugging the micro usb part into that just to make sure the micro usb part even works.